# MySQL 5.7 exclusive lock on table and shared_read locks causes deadlock/freeze

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, mysql-5.7

I'm altering a table to add a comment, the type and other parameters of the column are not changing:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
COMMENT 'test1';
```

When I try and run this change on a production server with a moderate amount of traffic, I see what looks like a deadlock scenario. Requests asking for SHARED_READ locks cannot proceed (they are PENDING) and the EXCLUSIVE lock is also PENDING, so the system freezes and cannot process queries against the table.

Looking at the documentation, MySQL should be able to to a DDR while allowing DML transactions on an innodb table. Is there something I am missing?

Using the following Query I can see the locks:

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_DURATION, LOCK_STATUS, OWNER_THREAD_ID, PROCESSLIST_ID, PROCESSLIST_HOST, PROCESSLIST_STATE, PROCESSLIST_INFO, PROCESSLIST_TIME

FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks 
LEFT JOIN performance_schema.threads ON threads.THREAD_ID = metadata_locks.OWNER_THREAD_ID

order by owner_thread_id DESC;
```

Is this just how MySQL works, that you can't functionally change a table on a system with a moderate amount of traffic?

```
OBJECT_TYP OBJECT_SCHEMA     OBJECT_NAME   LOCK_TYPE           LOCK_DURATION LOCK_STATUS OWNER_THREAD_ID  PROCESSLIST_ID PROCESSLIST_HOST PROCESSLIST_STATE          PROCESSLIST_INFO                PROCESSLIST_TIME
TABLE      main_db           table2        SHARED_READ         TRANSACTION   GRANTED     80801101         80801075       IP2              Waiting for table metadata SELECT FROM table1              16
TABLE      main_db           table1        SHARED_READ         TRANSACTION   PENDING     80801101         80801075       IP2              Waiting for table metadata SELECT FROM table1              16
TABLE      main_db           table1        SHARED_READ         TRANSACTION   PENDING     80799419         80799393       IP1              Waiting for table metadata SELECT FROM table1 and table2   11
GLOBAL     NULL              NULL          INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE STATEMENT     GRANTED     80777210         80777184       IP1              Waiting for table metadata ALTER TABLE table1 add comment  17
SCHEMA     main_db           NULL          INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION   GRANTED     80777210         80777184       IP1              Waiting for table metadata ALTER TABLE table1 add comment  17
TABLE      main_db           table1        SHARED_UPGRADABLE   TRANSACTION   GRANTED     80777210         80777184       IP1              Waiting for table metadata ALTER TABLE table1 add comment  17
TABLE      main_db           table1        EXCLUSIVE           TRANSACTION   PENDING     80777210         80777184       IP1              Waiting for table metadata ALTER TABLE table1 add comment  17
```

If I leave it for 30 seconds, it still won't progress to acquiring a lock to alter the table, and will block the selects.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is not properly called a deadlock. A deadlock is when two or more transactions are in a cycle of lock-wait dependencies on each other, so there is no way to break the wait. In this case, there's nothing to do but kill one of the transactions. I don't think I've ever seen a deadlock involving metadata locks in MySQL, only row locks.

What you're seeing is how MySQL metadata locks work. These are different from row locks in the InnoDB storage engine.

Any DDL statement, even one that only changes a comment so it's a metadata-only change, requires an exclusive metadata lock.

But any session that is reading or writing that table holds a shared metadata lock until its transaction ends. Shared metadata locks block exclusive metadata lock requests. Exclusive means no other session may hold any metadata lock, shared or otherwise, so the metadata lock request waits for all sessions to finish their transactions and release their shared metadata locks.

Once the DDL statement begins waiting for its exclusive metadata lock, all other sessions that want to run simple queries need their shared metadata locks, and the outstanding DDL lock request blocks them. So they wait too. In this way, a single DDL statement waiting can hold up everyone who starts their request after the DDL statement starts waiting.

Why is the DDL statement waiting? Because one or more of the sessions that were holding shared metadata locks at the time the DDL statement started won't give up their metadata locks. They could be running a very long-lived query, but it's also possible that their query is finished, and they just won't COMMIT or ROLLBACK to release their locks. This is up to application code design.

You should code your application to make transactions as short as possible:

- Optimize individual queries so they don't run too long.
- Don't group too many unrelated queries into a single transaction. Transactions should represent a finite group of queries that need to be in the same transaction. I've seen some developers group an unbounded number of queries together into a single long-lived transaction for no good reason.
- Do all the queries together in the transaction without unnecessary non-database code between them, and then COMMIT or ROLLBACK as promptly as possible. I've seen transactions become long-lived unexpectedly in some applciations because in between the queries, the application did an http request to a web service or something else that took a long time. Meanwhile, the database transaction went on too long in its uncommitted state.

Does a metadata lock request time out like a row lock request? Yes, there is a timeout, but the default duration of the timeout for a metadata lock request is **1 year** (this is the value of [`lock_wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lock_wait_timeout) configuration variable).

Can you reduce the metadata lock request timeout? Yes, you can. In a schema-change management application I worked on at one job, we set the `lock_wait_timeout` to 2 seconds, so if the application was busy, at least the DDL statement wouldn't cause a bad logjam (well, not more than 2 seconds per request; this might be somewhat bad if the other sessions need to run queries that finish in milliseconds).

Then our service would retry the DDL statement if it timed out. It would retry up to 200 times after brief sleep intervals. If it still failed (it could fail for example if there was never a moment where it could slip in between long-running transactions run by other sessions), then the schema change would fail and an error would be returned. This meant the change must be tried some other time, hopefully when traffic is lighter.